# Is there an Ektron Scheduler?

Tags: ektron

I need to have a process or widget that every five minutes will check to see if there are any xlf files in the localization folder, and if any exist, will import them into Ektron.  Is there a way within Ektron to have something scheduled.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any scheduler program inside Ektron.

To schedule a task you could look at using one of the following:

- [Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)
- Command line programs called by Task Scheduler

Alternatively, you could look at using an Ektron plugin, which will get fired when certain Ektron events occur (e.g. content published). However, in my experience plugins/extensions are poorly supported and documented.

Comment: Quartz.Net is a good suggestion. I couldn't remember what it was called. I'll agree that plugins weren't great, but I'm a big fan of the extension support in recent versions.

Comment: What I am looking to do is programatically import content by checking the localization folder every X minutes.  What is the best way to do that?  I didn't see a localization API in the web services.

Answer (score 2):

You can try creating a Windows service to perform the scheduling.

Details on the localization API and how localization performed can be found at:

**root\Workarea\controls\content\localization_uc.ascx.cs**  in your Ektron site.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend trying something similar to what Ken McAndrew did for an alias scheduler. Details here: [Manual Alias Scheduler](http://developer.ektron.com/Templates/CodeLibraryDetail.aspx?id=490&blogid=116)